# What `bazel` dependency to be able to `import "protoc-gen-openapiv2/options/annotations.proto"`?

Tags: bazel, grpc-gateway, protoc-gen-openapiv2

I'm trying to create Swagger documentation for proto files and would like to `import "protoc-gen-openapiv2/options/annotations.proto";` to do so. What `bazel` dependency is needed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/blob/master/protoc-gen-openapiv2/options/BUILD.bazel#L21-L22 has:

```
proto_library(
    name = "options_proto",
    …
)
```

indicating the dependency ends in `//protoc-gen-openapiv2/options:options_proto`.

https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/blob/master/WORKSPACE#L1 has:

```
workspace(name = "grpc_ecosystem_grpc_gateway")
```

indicating the repo to use is `@grpc_ecosystem_grpc_gateway`.

So the full dependency would be:

```
deps = ["@grpc_ecosystem_grpc_gateway//protoc-gen-openapiv2/options:options_proto"]
```